# Access denied when attempting to connect to MySQL from jsp in NetBeans

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, netbeans, jakarta-ee

I'm trying run a simple Java/MySQL web app tutorial in NetBeans.

I am able to connect to my database from a standard Java program in NetBeans, and Tomcat is working.  But when I try to connect to the database from a JSP, I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid:
"org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory 
(Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))"
```

I know I have the correct password set, since other (Java SE) programs can connect to the database.  Can anyone point me where to look?

I'm using NetBeans 6.7, MySQL 5.1, and Tomcat 6.0.18 in Windows Vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username `root` can be used to login from the same machine only and not remotely. Try creating another user ID with all permissions.

have a look at [Adding user accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html). In that page you will see two queries

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

Here the 2nd `monty@%` can be used to login remotely whereas the first is restricted to local login.

Comment: Well that worked, but not for the reason you thought it might.  It turned out that my password was misspelled in context.xml.  Nevertheless, your suggested change led me to check, so full credit.